# Doctrine inextricable string of require_once dependancies

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, pear

I am trying to use a pear installation of Doctrine, it seems like all of the Requires and Class Names are just looking in the wrong places... do I need to be updating this all in cli-config.php (or similar file)? I don't understand how to get all of these things resolved.

before I go hard-coding all of the requires, I assume there is an elegant way to get this to work. for instance...

> Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration' not found in
>   /usr/local/pear/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php on line 41

so my pear install path is `/usr/local/pear` and the pear doctrine install seems to be `/usr/local/pear/share/pear/Doctrine`

I have been reading documents, and it seems to work in the sandbox from the cli, but, I don't really have a very modern understanding of PHP. I have been looking through the documentation, and there is probably a very simple step that I am missing, but I do not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running php like

```
php -d include_path=/usr/local/pear/share/pear
```

if this works, you may be missing that path in your include_path

try to issue a phpinfo() or var_dump(ini_get('include_path')) to actually see your include path, the directory Doctrine should be located somewhere inside that path

Comment: I certainly think you have put me on the right track... for whatever reason I have those added by go pear. and they show up in the phpinfo()   maybe I broke it earlier feebly trying to fix it some other way.

Comment: if the command above worked from the console, just edit your php.ini and add that include path. another option is to write an .htaccess (if using apache) so you can php_value include_path "the:path"

Comment: no it didn't work and the path is already included, but I think I am closer to understanding how this all works. I will accept as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: are you using php 5.2? doctrine2 only works in php 5.3+ because it uses namespaces. also, you are going to need an autoloader (either the one that comes with doctrine2 or some other, like the one for zend framework, ding, etc). this autoloader will replace the \ by /, so it will get to the correct path/class files

Comment: 5.3, I will post my configuration file.